# Undefined variable: _ENV in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables, vendor

I was testing my system with Laravel 5.3:

For past few weeks my system was working fine. Since last weekend, I encountered the same error **TWICE** as below:-

> Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in C:\NewFolder\htdocs\project\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Loader.php on line 303
>
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\NewFolder\htdocs\project\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Loader.php on line 303

**Loader.php:**

```
public function getEnvironmentVariable($name)
{
    switch (true) {
        case array_key_exists($name, $_ENV): // line 303 here
            return $_ENV[$name];
        case array_key_exists($name, $_SERVER):
            return $_SERVER[$name];
        default:
            $value = getenv($name);
            return $value === false ? null : $value;
    }
}
```

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:oTU0Ok1mmE6x0qEosGKhCSxpQLAlBAnNreH7sFAKkdM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=new_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_ID=
```

- When the above error appeared on the first time(when I loaded login page), I cleared my browser cache and history, the system managed to back to normal.
- When the same error appeared on second time(in the mid of testing process), I did the same as first time, cleared browser cache and history, but it could not helped, the error still show after I refreshed my browser. So I executed `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` but still failed to get back to normal.

Anyone have any idea on why is this happening? Thanks

**The version I used:**

- OS: Window 7
- Browser: Mozilla Firefox
- PHP: 7.1.1
- Laravel: 5.3

Comment: That's weird, [it should be there](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.environment.php)

Comment: did you try update your app using composer update?

Comment: Run: `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @HirenGohel Pretty sure OP says in dot-point #2 that they have tried `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @Phil Yeah, my mistake. Sorry for that! Agree with you.

Comment: In laravel you can access environment variables using `env('Variable_name')` example `env('APP_DEBUG', false)` where first param is variable name and second is default value

Comment: It's an error in `vlucas\phpdotenv\` so update the package

Comment: Which version of `PHP` you are using ? what value you set for `register_long_arrays` in `php.ini` ?

Comment: @user2486 I am using PHP 7.1.1 and `register_long_arrays=Off`

Comment: @user2486 `register_long_arrays` was removed in PHP 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some finding and research, I found there are some similar issues from [Github #8191](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8191).

I able to get rid of the error by running `php artisan config:cache`. Means that Laravel will read the environment variable from the config file rather than reading the environment variable directly from .env

Answer (score 5):

The only reason the `$_ENV` super-global should not be defined is if it has been removed from the [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) configuration.

Check your `php.ini` (or any other relevant config files) for the `variables_order` property. For `$_ENV` to be set, it **must** include an *"E"*. The default setting is

```
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

If you're having trouble locating the configuration, a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` dump should also show the value and config file locations.

`variables_order` is a [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://php.net/manual/configuration.changes.modes.php) mode setting, meaning...

> Entry can be set in *php.ini*, *.htaccess*, *httpd.conf* or *.user.ini* (since PHP 5.3)

The characters stand for

- *E* - `$_ENV`
- *G* - `$_GET`
- *P* - `$_POST`
- *C* - `$_COOKIE`
- *S* - `$_SERVER`

Answer (score 1):

Old question but at 2021 found same error and solved:

Use https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset in Laravel 7

**Solution**:

Instead of @foreach in your blade templates

use:

```
@php
foreach(){}
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly an error outside of the scope of your code; it is a change with your dependencies or your system configuration.  You should consider rebuilding your dependency cache, and rolling back to old version of dependencies prior to the date when the error started.

As @MahdiYounesi said, start with the `phpdotenv` dependency.